# ERROR when working with HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

when i try to generate a pdf with html2pdf it gives this error : [ERROR] It seems that HTML2PDF dependencies are not installed... you must install thems with `composer install`
what should i do ?
PS: i've already installed composer.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem with you finally i down grade to v.4.4.0 and worked fine

Comment: Downgraded PHP ?

Comment: @user3526204 no, downgrade html2pdf to 4.4.0 - that is the final version made in 2015 that had dependencies included. All versions starting with 4.5.0+ need composer to install dependencies. Here is a link to download 4.4.0: https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/releases/tag/v4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

For those who looking for the answer.you can find the solution in README file : 
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/README.md